# How can i set a DataItem to some part of aspx code?

Tags: asp.net, dataitem

I have some code like this:

```
<div><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "M_ClassProperty") %></div>
<img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "M_AnotherClassProperty").To<string>()  %>'
```

but there is no component which wraps this code like Repeater, DataList or something like that. How can set the set a DataItem to this code to show the values of an object of a class.

I hope i could tell clear (I don't think so but I HOPE :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normal inline code, like this:

```
<div> <%= SomeObject.SomeProperty.ToString() %></div>
```

To get an object, you can define a protected property in the code-behind page.